# Задать глобальный стиль для popup/tooltip/title

Tags: html, css

Есть простой `<span title="заполните поле">*</span>`

и блок `<div class="doccontrolattributestext" title="anytext">`

У них присутствует title что и выводится в popup. Как-то можно глобально переопределить его. Например поставить `color:red` и изменить фон для popup

Answer (score 0):

Встроенная всплывающая подсказка не управляется CSS. 
Используйте решения на js, которые создают popup-ы из верстки, там можно управлять всем.